# copy database from assets to databases folder

Tags: android, database, copy

In main activity I have this method which copies files from `assets` to the `databases` folder:

```
try{
    // CHECK IS EXISTS OR NOT
    SQLiteDatabase dbe = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.henanet.dalel/databases/mydb.sqlite",null, 0);
    dbe.close();
    // COPY IF NOT EXISTS
    AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.henanet.dalel/databases/mydb.sqlite");
    byte[] b = new byte[100];
    int r;
    InputStream is = am.open("mydb.sqlite");
    while ((r = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, r);
    }
    is.close();
    os.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

But once the user installs the app, he gets this error in LogCat:

```
09-14 22:57:25.694: I/Database(19903): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot               open file at source line 25467
09-14 22:57:25.694: E/Database(19903): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.henanet.dalel/databases/mydb.sqlite", &handle, 2, NULL) failed
```

Comment: How have you created db you are trying to open from '/data/data' folder. Android expect `android_metadata`, `local` table in each db.

Comment: @new Ques check my answer it may help

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My method

Get Your Database path using the following

```
ContextWrapper cw =new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
DB_PATH =cw.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/databases/"; //edited to databases
```

Then you can go this way

```
private void copyDataBase()
    {
        Log.i("Database",
                "New database is being copied to device!");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        int length;
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = null;
        try
        {
            myInput =myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the
            // outputfile
            myOutput =new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH+ DB_NAME);
            while((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.close();
            myOutput.flush();
            myInput.close();
            Log.i("Database",
                    "New database has been copied to device!");


        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think at the `DB_PATH =cw.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/Database/"` the last word, **Database** should be `/databases/`

Comment: Actually, as per @CommonsWare suggestion in the alternative post answering this question, paths should never be hardcoded. That is entering `"/Database/"`; instead, Use `getDatabasePath()` to derive the path for a database file.

Comment: to get the db path:getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath();

Comment: that's not working in my case