# how to add pre-made database .db file to Android using LibGDX

Tags: java, android, sqlite, libgdx

I am programming Android using LibGDX. I have pre-made database file. I can make database on android at runtime using this [wraper](https://github.com/mrafayaleem/gdx-sqlite), but I can't figure out how to use already made one.

I tried 2 ways to get it done:

**1.** To use [this DataBaseHelper class example](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/), but while in Android, I would just write:

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
```

in LibGDX I run into problem:

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper();  <--requires variable "android.content.Context"
```

**2.** Using internal file handler of LibGDX:

```
FileHandle mHandle = Gdx.files.internal("list.db");
mydb1 = DatabaseFactory.getNewDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,DATABASE_VERSION, DATABASE_CREATE, null);
```

but I don't know how to make contact between mHandle and mydb1.

Any ideas welcome how to do it in LibGdx, thanx

Comment: You can copy the DB to the assets folder and then at runtime copy it to the database directory as explaned [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207581/android-copying-database-from-asset-folder