# Error no such table while running in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i am now created a database and i had created a table called GAME with fields...i wrote select query for this table to check field existence....while running my code for accessing the table it shows no such table exception.....i have created that table in SQlite manager not in code..i dono why this error showing...the database contains table in assets folder....please explain why this error.....please help me.....thanks in advance

```
objdatabase.rawQuery("SELECT ADMIN_ACCESS_CODE,ACCESS_CODE FROM GAME WHERE ADMIN_ACCESS_CODE='"+strPassword+"'", null);
```

Comment: Is the table's name GAME or Game or game?

Comment: yup its GAME only......:-(

Comment: Just because the database file is on assets folder that doesn't mean it's on android system. Can you show us the code where you copy it from the assets to the android system?

Comment: i have copied the whole database from another application and paste that in asset folder directly not in code....

Comment: Yes. But that's how it works. Your sql query will be executed on the android system. Not in the file on the assets folder. Refer to this to copy the database from the assets folder to the system. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805874/copy-database-from-assets-to-databases-folder

Comment: y so....is it not enough just copying...?????

Comment: Refer this link for handling database from assets folder : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605555/android-accessing-assets-folder-sqlite-database-file-with-sqlite-extension

Comment: have you used your DDMS Perspective to check whether the database actually exists before querying

Comment: yes i have wrote this code checkdatabase() but its returning true everytime...:-(

Comment: nope.......i havent used that perspective yet.....what it is used for.....please tell me the usage...@danidee

Comment: sorry yES YES i have used that prespective..but that shows database saved in emulator storage only know..@danidee

Answer (score -1):

```
objdatabase.rawQuery("SELECT `ADMIN_ACCESS_CODE`,`ACCESS_CODE` FROM `GAME` WHERE `ADMIN_ACCESS_CODE`='"+strPassword+"'", null);
```

try this