# No such file or directory on device

Tags: android, sqlite

In my activity I create an object to copy a database from asset folder to app database, everything works fine in emulator but in the device, I get no such file or directory Error on

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);
```

I have permission needed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I call in MainActivity:

```
db = new ExternalDB(this);
```

and in ExternalDB (Is SqliteOpenHelper):

```
ExternalDB(Context context){
    super(context, DB_Name, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    mycontext = context;
    AssetDatabaseOpenHelper adb = new AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(context,DB_Name);
    db = adb.OpenDatabase();
}
```

And AssetDatabaseOpenHelper:

```
public class AssetDatabaseOpenHelper {

private static String DB_NAME;

private Context context;

AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String DB_NAME){
    this.context = context;
    AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.DB_NAME = DB_NAME;
}

public SQLiteDatabase OpenDatabase(){
    File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);

    if(!dbFile.exists()){
        try{
            CopyDatabase(dbFile);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            throw  new RuntimeException("Error Creating source database", e);
        }
    }

  //  copyDataBase();
    return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(),null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
private void CopyDatabase(File dbFile) throws IOException{
    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    while(is.read(buffer)>0){
        os.write(buffer);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
}
}
```

As I Mentioned i get this error on this line:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);
```

Comment: There's a solution to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805874/copy-database-from-assets-to-databases-folder/18806587)

Comment: @Ten I get exact same error when i use method mentioned in question you referenced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Any One having same problem, Hard Coding database paths didn't work for me and finaly writing copy function like this solved my problem:

```
    /**
 * Copy database file from assets folder inside the apk to the system database path.
 * @param context Context
 * @param databaseName Database file name inside assets folder
 * @param overwrite True to rewrite on the database if exists
 * @return True if the database have copied successfully or if the database already exists without overwrite, false otherwise.
 */
private boolean copyDatabaseFromAssets(Context context, String databaseName , boolean overwrite)  {

    File outputFile = context.getDatabasePath(databaseName);
    if (outputFile.exists() && !overwrite) {
        return true;
    }

    outputFile = context.getDatabasePath(databaseName + ".temp");
    outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(databaseName);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);


        // transfer bytes from the input stream into the output stream
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        outputFile.renameTo(context.getDatabasePath(databaseName));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (outputFile.exists()) {
            outputFile.delete();
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I had to create the folder databases first and then try to create database file.

from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29058717/4225644

Answer (score 1):

`CopyDatabase` get's called when `dbFile` **does not exist**. Right? And then you tell the `FileOutputStream` to open the `dbFile` which we have established **does not exist**. Thus, **no such file or directory Error**. Seems legit, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The error is arising because the folder "databases" does not exist so the database cannot be copied

Try:

```
  public SQLiteDatabase OpenDatabase() {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            try {

                //check if "databases" folder exists and create it if needed
                File destDir = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getParentFile();
                if(!destDir.exists()){
                    destDir.mkdirs();
                }

                CopyDatabase(dbFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error Creating source database", e);
            }
        } // copyDataBase();
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
```